# WordPress: How to do shortlink for my post URL

Tags: wordpress

I have site in wordpress, And i wont to create custom shortlink for post URL from :-

```
www.domainname.com/post-titel
```

to

```
http://dom.me/1DOJzXE
```

When Share it in social media.

How can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WordPress ShortLinks**

You can install the WordPress JetPack suite of tools and use "Shortlinks"

http://jetpack.me/support/wp-me-shortlinks/

**Custom Shortlinks**

If you want to use something similar to your own domain:

- Step 1: Buy a short domain name
- Step 2: Setup Custom Domain in Bit.ly
- Step 3:  Set an A Record to Point to Bit.ly
- Step 4: Verify Your Site
- Step 6: Install and setup [Official Bitly Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bitly/)

Answer (score 0):

[Go to Wordpress support page. Good example on page](https://en.support.wordpress.com/shortlinks/)

1. Go to Posts/Pages -> Add New or open an existing post/page in editing mode.
2. Directly under the title field, next to the post/page Permalink, you will see the Get Shortlink button.
   3.Click Get Shortlink and a dialog box will appear with the post/page’s shortlink. Copy it and share it with the world.

Comment: Hi, please don't just paste links on Stack Overflow as answers. This answer will be reported for inappropriateness.

Comment: Thank you. Please read this before answering anymore questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer